# Why do clothes washed with my new Samsung top load washer have an odor?

Tags: washing-machine

New top load washer that we purchased about 5 months ago is putting off a bad smell to washed clothing.  I wouldn’t think the washer is dirty already. Any help would be great.

Comment: We'll need some more details to help. Please [edit] in details like the model number, details about the smell and perhaps anything you noticed when it started doing this.

Comment: Could also the ["smelly towels"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=smelly+towels&oq=smelly+towels&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.16603j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) effect. You notice it when clothes are warm and damp, but it's not the washer's fault.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue with our new top load Kenmore. There's too much moisture staying inside the machine after a wash cycle.

Our solution was to buy washing machine cleaner and run a clean cycle, then simply leave the lid open unless we were doing a load of laundry.

Comment: I forgot to add that we always leave the top of the washer open for hours after use.

Answer (score 2):

My Samsung top loader manual specifically stated to leave the lid open after use. It also says to use the "clean" cycle once a month.

Answer (score 1):

Check the instructions. There is a machine clean cycle called Pure Cycle, pg 30 of our instructions.

I think the agitation is very vigorous and Pure Cycle is NOT to be used with clothes, but only to clean the machine.  This washer is designed to be water saving and perhaps needs to be cleaned this way periodically. We have had a Samsung top loader for several years and have had no smell. We haven't had to use the machine clean cycle, AFIK, but different needs for different users.

EDIT

We have since used the machine clean "Pure Cycle" once or twice just as a precaution.